# mysql update values in same table without using temporary table using update

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update or rather swap values between rows in the same table using update statement. I don't want to use a temporary table but do the update in a single statement. Below is the data

```
ID  Toy Color
1   Car red
2   barbie red
3   moto blue
4   cloud blue
```

I want to swap red with blue color keeping id's and other data same. I have tried the below statement but only one color gets updated and other is set to 0.

```
UPDATE test1 t1, test1 t2 SET t1.Color = 'blue' and t2.Color = 'red' WHERE t1.Color = 'red' and t2.Color = 'blue';
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` is a SQL boolean operator, not a list separator. You need to use a comma (`,`) in your list of fields to update:

```
UPDATE test1 t1, test1 t2 SET t1.Color = 'blue', t2.Color = 'red' WHERE t1.Color = 'red' and t2.Color = 'blue';
--                                             ^ comma here
```

In practical terms, this is going to require a Cartesian product of the table against itself. Based on your comments, you have 500k actual rows, so that would be an in-memory table with something like 25,000,000,000 rows. So, not the best approach.

If you're really just switching two values like this, you may find it easier to do a temporary substitution, rather than a join:

```
UPDATE test1 SET Color = 'TEMP' WHERE Color = 'red';
UPDATE test1 SET Color = 'red' WHERE Color = 'blue';
UPDATE test1 SET Color = 'blue' WHERE Color = 'TEMP';
```

Comment: is there a better way to do this using joins? I just gave an example table but I'll be using the concept in a table of more than 500k rows. I am trying to see is it better to do it with aliasing a table of using joins.

Comment: @ash There's probably a better way to do it, yes, but it's hard to say without knowing exactly what you want to do. The best thing to do is go ahead and prepare the query you're thinking about using, see how it works, then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about any problems you run into. If you're really just switching two values like this, you may find it easier to do a temporary substitution (change 'red' to 'temp', 'blue' to 'red', and 'temp' to 'blue', for example), rather than a join.

Comment: Understood that. As per concept do joins create a in memory temp table or to that fact the update statement you gave, do they create a temp table?

Comment: @ash If you use a comma (equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`) and the kind of `WHERE` condition that you have here, yes, the engine will create a temporary table in memory. From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html): "INNER JOIN and `,` (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table)." With 500k rows, that requires a *lot* of comparisons, which is why you may need a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Ed Cottrell

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `JOIN` as well.

```
UPDATE test1 T1
INNER JOIN test1 T2 ON T1.Color = 'red' and T2.Color = 'blue'
SET T1.Color = 'blue', T2.Color = 'red'
```

Hope this helps.